Terraform: How to pass value to an environment variable in local-exec?
I am trying to pass write the public IP address of a VM out to a text file via using locals and local-exec, see below code.
The issue is that the locals variable does not seem to work:
 my_ip=data.azurerm_public_ip.vm-publicip.ip_address

I tried passing the "data.azurerm_public_ip.vm-publicip.ip_address" inside local-exec at the environments too, but that also does not work.
Full code:
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "public"{
  name = "vm_public_ip"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  location = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  allocation_method = "Dynamic"

}

data "azurerm_public_ip" "vm-publicip"{
  name = azurerm_public_ip.public.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
}
locals {
  my_ip=data.azurerm_public_ip.vm-publicip.ip_address
  my_vm="[azure_vm]"
} 

resource "terraform_data" "ansible" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    environment = {
      VM=local.my_vm
      IP=data.azurerm_public_ip.vm-publicip.ip_address
    }
    command = "echo %VM% %IP%  > ansible_inventory"
  }
}

When I tried to run it, %VM% worked correctly, but the %IP% not.

Have you tried setting the interpreter: interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-Command"]?

Have you tried something like: command = "echo ${local.my_vm} ${data.azurerm_public_ip.vm-publicip.ip_address} > ansible_inventory"?

Or even better: command = "echo ${local.my_vm} ${local.my_ip} > ansible_inventory"

The Terraform documentation notes that provisioners are a last resort and that you should seek other alternatives before using them. This comment is therefore about a different way to solve this problem not using local-exec at all, because it isn't necessary to use an external program written in another language just to create a file containing some data produced by Terraform.
The Terraform provider hashicorp/local includes the resource type local_file which manages a file on local disk in a similar way to how azurerm_public_ip manages a remote object in the Azure API. You can use that resource type to instruct Terraform to create or update a file based on other data available in the Terraform configuration.
For example:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
    }
    local = {
      source = "hashicorp/local"
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "public" {
  name                = "vm_public_ip"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  allocation_method   = "Dynamic"
}

data "azurerm_public_ip" "vm-publicip" {
  name                = azurerm_public_ip.public.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
}

locals {
  my_ip = data.azurerm_public_ip.vm-publicip.ip_address
  my_vm = "[azure_vm]"
}

resource "local_file" "ansible_inventory" {
  file    = "${path.module}/ansible_inventory"
  content = "${local.my_vm} ${data.azurerm_public_ip.vm-publicip.ip_address}"
}

When the local_file.ansible_inventory resource is created, it will create the ansible_inventory file and write the content value into it. If you subsequently change the value of local.my_vm or data.azurerm_public_ip.vm-publicip.ip_address, the provider will propose to rewrite the file with the new information.

The local_file documentation has the following warning, but a similar situation would've been true for the local-exec approach too, so I assume it's not a concern for your situation:

When working with local files, Terraform will detect the resource as having been deleted each time a configuration is applied on a new machine where the file is not present and will generate a diff to re-create it. This may cause "noise" in diffs in environments where configurations are routinely applied by many different users or within automation systems.

